# Rails MVC: Combine data from two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm looking at statistics on "Cars" & "Trucks."  I have a model for each which tidies up the raw data and returns it in a common format.

Then in the view I have a single "Vehicles" chart which integrates data from the two sources.

Where in my application should this integration happen?

- In the Vehicles controller?
- In some kind of read-only Vehicles model not backed by a database table?
- In lib?
- ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of different ways. You can have a `Vehicle` class which cars and trucks inherit from `Cars << Vehicle` `Trucks << Vehicle`

You can have only a Vehicle table, and have a `VehicleType` column with different types for cars and trucks

You can do it in the controller / view where, if the data is formatted the same, in the controller you can have all the cars and trucks into an `@vehicle` variable that gets passed to a view.

If cars and trucks are essentially the same, I would use a VehicleType column in the same table. If you need them to have the same methods, but those methods are implemented differently, I would use a Vehicle base class and have cars and trucks inherit from that.

Comment: Rails has built in support for this - STI, single table inheritance, http://blog.eizesus.com/2009/10/sti-best-practices-in-rails/ - use a column named type to hold the objects type

Comment: Solomon, house9 - Much appreciated.  I will give these suggestions a try.